# Benefits of using Intellij IDEA as Mathematica IDE?

Tags: programming, notebooks, interface

I use Intellij IDEA for Java programming, but have not really considered it for Mathematica. I saw a video with a Wolfram programmer who was describing it as "essential" for him, but from what I could gather of what he said, most of the benefits for him were either workgroup related (sharing code with other Wolfram programmers) or were doing things involving "internal" Mathematica code, not notebook code/problem solving.

So, for a person doing normal Mathematica calculations and models in the science world, what, if any, are the significant benefits to using Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Read halirutan's post: [Open-source IntelliJIDEA plugin to support Mathematica development](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556) In there, he lays out the benefits of using IntelliJ IDEA for _Mathematica_ and also describes the features of the plugin (actively developed by him) which helps you with _Mathematica_ programming. I use it regularly and the features so far implemented in the plugin totally blow away WRI's in-house product, the Wolfram WorkBench (Eclipse based). The rest of the features in WB can also be implemented, but it's a matter of time (it's a 1 man show so far).

Comment: In any case, I would consider this post a duplicate of his, since he lays out the benefits of the IDE in the question.

Comment: I might also add that there are other questions, such as [getting serious about mathematica programming](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29094/7167) that touch upon this and other aspects of structuring your Mathematica programming.

Comment: Both Workbench and IDEA are great for package development, where you are working on a set of functions to be re-used many times, improving them incrementally, and packaging them up for convenience.  They are not suitable for interactive work such as data analysis, but they're great for working with source code.